# I'm trying to download captions from youtube data api but I'm running into an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using googleapi in node.js server to extract captions from youtube video given a video ID. I have enabled youtube data api in google cloud, used the proper clientID and client secret.

it's throwing this error: Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set. for this block of code:

```
 const captionsResponse = await youtube.captions.list({
      part: "snippet",
      videoId: videoId,
    });
```

here is my complete code:

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;

const router = express.Router();

const clientId =process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirectUri = process.env.REDIRECT-URI;
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);

// Set up YouTube API client
const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: "v3",
  auth: oauth2Client,
});

router.get("/:videoId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { videoId } = req.params;

    
    // Call the captions.list method to get the captions for the specified video
    const captionsResponse = await youtube.captions.list({
      part: "snippet",
      videoId: videoId,
    });
    if (captionsResponse.data.items.length === 0) {
      res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: "This video doesn't have a transcript!",
      });
      return;
    }

    // Get the ID of the first caption
    const captionId = captionsResponse.data.items[0].id;

    // Call the captions.download method to get the transcript text
    const transcriptResponse = await youtube.captions.download({
      id: captionId,
      tfmt: "vtt", // Specify the format of the transcript (e.g., WebVTT)
    });

    const transcriptText = transcriptResponse.data;

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, transcript: transcriptText });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ success: false, message: "Failed to retrieve transcript" });
  }
});



module.exports = router;
```

what I expect to get is the transcript text

Comment: Try another tool.  I can download Youtube video transcripts with command line tool `yt-dlp` (eg `yt-dlp --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-format json3 $target_url`).  If you get it to work, then you can find a JavaScript library that wraps `yt-dlp`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do pretty much samething, your API call is missing an access token, try adding yout api key in the query parameters also. But this specific endpoint requires O2Auth token.

I try to get an existing caption using its ID but I get a 404 error.

Console log your Access Token to verify if it exists and its not expired.